# Search Strings in a List with Loop Return Order

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm very new to Python and I have a question.

I have a List that looks like this:

```
  List = ["B-Guild","I-Guild","I-Guild","L-Guild","B-Gene","L-Gene","U-Car"]
```

All of the words with B-(I)-L belong to each other and I want to use a function to show that.

```
def combine(x):
 foo = []
 regexp_B = ("B-" + r'.*')
 regexp_I = ("I-" + r'.*')
 regexp_L = ("L-" + r'.*')
 regexp_U = ("U-" + r'.*')
 for i in range(0,len(x),1):
    if re.match(regexp_B, x[i]):
        print("Found B")
        foo.append[i+x[i]]
        if re.match(regexp_I, x[i+1]):
            print("Found I")
            foo.append[i+1+x[i+1]]
            if re.match(regexp_I, x[i+1]):
                print("Found I")
                foo.append[i+1+x[i+1]]
            else:
                print("Found L")
                foo.append[i+1+x[i+1]]  
        else:
            print("Found L")
            foo.append[i1+x[i1]]    
    elif re.match(regexp_L, x[i]):
        print("L")
        foo.append[i1+x[i1]]    
    elif re.match(regexp_U, x[i]):
        print("Found U")
        foo.append[i1+x[i1]]
return foo

List_New = combine(List)
```

Desired Output:

```
foo = ["0B-Guild","0I-Guild","0I-Guild","OL-Guild","1B-Gene","1L-Gene","2U-Car"]
```

Edit:

The output follows this logic: Every time a `"B-"` prefix appears, the words to follow are part of one "theme" until a `"L-"` prefix appears. These words got to have the same number before them so they can be grouped for further functions. `"U-"` prefixes don't follow that logic and just need a number before them to distinguish them from the other words. Think of it as a Counter that groups these word into a cluster.

Comment: What *does* the program do?  "does not work at all" is not a problem specification.

Comment: Please explain the output logic.  "B-I-L belong to each other" is not sufficient to detail the logic of your number prefixes.  I strongly suspect that your logic and `regex` are overkill for what you need to do.

Comment: I'm very uncertain what the prefixes have to do with it. It seems like the suffix is what's determining what number you add to the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def combine(some_list):
    current_group = 0 # starts with 0
    g_size = 0 # current group size
    for elem in some_list:
        g_size += 1
        if elem.startswith('U-') and g_size > 1:
            g_size = 1 
            current_group += 1
        yield '{}{}'.format(current_group, elem)
        if elem.startswith(('L-', 'U-')): # each L- or U- also finishes a group
            g_size = 0
            current_group += 1



>>> List = ["B-Guild","I-Guild","I-Guild","L-Guild","B-Gene","L-Gene","U-Car"]
>>> print(list(combine(List)))

>>> List = ["B-Guild","I-Guild","I-Guild","L-Guild","B-Guild","L-Guild","U-Guild"]
>>> print(list(combine(List)))
```

Comment: Perfect! Does this also work if the List looks like this: `List = ["B-Guild","I-Guild","I-Guild","L-Guild","B-Guild","L-Guild","U-Guild"]`?

Comment: I guess you can try for yourself at this point, but this will work fine, it will return `['0B-Guild', '0I-Guild', '0I-Guild', '0L-Guild', '0B-Guild', '0L-Guild', '0U-Guild']` since it is grouping by whatever is after the `-` on each element, so that's all in the same group

Comment: Yeah. Although I'm expecting `['0B-Guild', '0I-Guild', '0I-Guild', '0L-Guild', '1B-Guild', '1L-Guild', '2U-Guild']` to be the results. I'll try it mysellf later. Thanks, man.

Comment: No, it will create a new number for each `U-` so `["U-Guild","U-Car","U-Gene"]` will return `['0U-Guild', '1U-Car', '2U-Gene']`. But I forgot to increment `g_size` so it wasn't working. Fixed now.

Comment: I also simplified the code a bit and added comments

Comment: Thank you so much ! It works perfect and also thanks for the input that he missed to increment. Lovely work :)